# Android - parse network dump (pcap)

Tags: android, parsing, networking, pcap

I am currently desperately looking for a possibility to parse tcpdump network dump files (tcpdump -w ) inside my android app. I really just need the parsing stuff - no sniffing.

Does anyone knows a proper library or something else to parse such dumps.
I can even adjust the output of tcpdump - just need to parse that output.

Thank you very much !

Greets

Btw: What I actually want to do is, to identify special strings in the traffic. So just knowing about source, destination, port, ... is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at

http://www.programming-pcap.aldabaknocking.com/code/simplesniffer.c

if pcap.h or pcap libraries are not available for android you have to write your own functions and structs

http://gotbrew.org/git/coolstuff/pcap2bin.c